# Why does the svg shape dissapear after setting the transform-origin to 50%?

Tags: css, svg

Transform-origin 50% 50% sets the center of scaling to the center of the element. So when I scale the element, it should just scale from the circles center meaning, the viewbox stays in place, and only the element scales from the elements center, but that's not what is happening. Is this actually setting the point of origin for the whole viewbox of the element?

```css
svg{
    border: 1px solid red;
}

circle{
    fill: red;
    fill-opacity: 50%;
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 1px;
}

circle:hover{
        transform:scale(2);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<svg width="800" height="600" viewBox="0 0 800 600">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I tried to explain both the problem and possible solution. I have considered 50px 50px in the transform. Because, it is the dimension of the circle. Hope this helps.. Good luck!

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

circle {
  fill: red;
  fill-opacity: 50%;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.problem circle:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.solution circle:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: 50px 50px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="problem" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20"/>
    </svg>

<svg class="solution" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20"/>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Robert closed the question (see top) because the correct answer, already given in another question, is: ``transform-origin: center center``